# Error building AngularJS application with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs

I'm trying to build a front-end application in AngularJS using RequireJS.

The application implements a master detail, using $http.get call to get some information from a web service RESTful application and display them in a table.
For every row, there is a button that use another $http.get to show other details.

Everything works.
However, there is something wrong using RequireJS.

This is the tree of my app:

```
script/
    main.js
    angularJS/
        angular.min.js
        masterDetailAppController.js
    requireJS/
        require.js
```

This is a **.jsp** managed by SpringMVC, it would be the index.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Master Detail</title>

    <!-- Inclusion of CSS -->
    <link href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Inclusion of requireJS -->
    <script data-main="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/script/main" 
            src="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/script/requireJS/require.js">
    </script>        
   </head>
<body>
    <h3>Master Detail</h3>        
    <div ng-app="masterDetailApp" ng-controller="masterDetailController" ng-init="query()">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Cognome</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row" ng-repeat="e in employees">
                <td>{{e.uid}}</td>
                <td>{{e.name}}</td>
                <td>{{e.surname}}</td>  
                <td><input type="button" ng-click="detail(e.uid)" value="Detail"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>            
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Main.js**

```
require.config({
"paths": {
    "angularJS": "angularJS/angular.min",
    "masterDetailAppController": "angularJS/masterDetailAppController"
}
});

require(["angularJS","masterDetailAppController"]);
```

**masterDetailAppController.js**

```
var app = angular.module("masterDetailApp", []);

app.controller("masterDetailController", ["$scope", "$http", function   ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.query = function () {
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulWebApp/api/players/list")
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.employees = response;
                });
    };
    $scope.detail = function (id) {
        var squadra, ruolo, numero, ris;
        $http.get("http://localhost:8080/RESTfulWebApp/api/players/" + id)
                .success(function (response) {
                    alert("Squadra: " + response.team + "\nRuolo: " + response.role + "\nMaglia: " + response.shirtNumber);

                });
    };

}
]);
```

**angular.min.js** and **require.js** are the libraries.

When I run the application, I get this errors:

1. Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=masterDetailApp&p1…2FHttpRequest%2Fresources%2Fscript%2FangularJS%2Fangular.min.js%3A344%3A20)
2. GET http://localhost:8080/HttpRequest/resources/script/angularJS/angular.min/angular.min.js
3. Uncaught Error: Script error for: angularJS/angular.min
   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
4. Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: masterDetailAppController
   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout

Why?